# htaccess redirecting nonexistent directory but not files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect a nonexistent virtual folder when it is directly accessed to the root domain but not files from within it. How to get this? Right now I can only redirect the full directory, including all files, to the domain with this in my .htaccess file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /features http://example.org/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The redirect is incorrect, should be:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/features/?$ http://example.org/
```

So you'll match only the path and not the files.
Consider also that with this solution the slash after the directory `features` is optional.